# Ordenação específica de uma lista sem plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, aplicação-web, slide

Estou enfrentando um problema bem específico em um projeto.
Estou criando slide, onde eu preciso ordernar a lista de acordo o que é clicado na paginação. Ela deve ficar da seguinte forma:

Seguinte forma:

```
Quando clico na paginação no item 3, a lista deve ficar da seguinte forma:

Lista original:       Lista MO
0                            2
1                           *3*
2                            4
3                            0
4                            1


----------


Quando clico na paginação no item 2, a lista deve ficar da seguinte forma:

Lista original:        Lista MO
0                            1
1                           *2*
2                            3
3                            4
4                            0


----------


Quando clico na paginação no item 0, a lista deve ficar da seguinte forma:

Lista original:        Lista MO
0                            4
1                           *0*
2                            1
3                            2
4                            3
```

Sempre será visível apenas o item da lista na posição 1. Como mostra na imagem a baixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quem puder ajudar, segue o **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luizpaulo165/ybuf4fju/)**, com uma base para testes, tanto pode ser feito em JS puro ou jQuery.

Comment: Bem vindo ao stackoverflow em Português! Acho que se enganou na imagem.

Comment: Acho que não se enganou. Ele está querendo fazer um slide :)

Answer (score 1):

Com a ajuda do pessoal do grupo Jquery Brasil, consegui resolver o problema. Para quem tiver interesse em ver o resultado:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li data-position="0">0</li>
    <li data-position="1">1</li>
    <li data-position="2">2</li>
    <li data-position="3">3</li>
    <li data-position="4">4</li>
</ul>

<ul class="pagination">
    <a href="#" data-position="0">0</a>
    <a href="#" data-position="1">1</a>
    <a href="#" data-position="2">2</a>
    <a href="#" data-position="3">3</a>
    <a href="#" data-position="4">4</a>
</ul>
```

```
$(function(){
    var list = $(".list li");
    var newList = new Array();

    $(".pagination a").bind("click", function(){
        var pageSelected = $(this);
        var afterPage = list.slice(pageSelected.data("position") - 1,list.length);
        var beforePage = list.slice(0, pageSelected.data("position") - 1);

        afterPage.each(function(a,b){
            newList.push(b);
        });

        beforePage.each(function(a,b){
            newList.push(b);
        });

        $(".list").append(newList);
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybuf4fju/6/)

Comment: Incluí o código pois é desejável que as respostas aqui sejam auto-suficientes (não dependam de links externos), ok?

Answer (score 0):

Baseando no seu JsFiddle, criei essa solução para seu problema.

Exemplo:

```
$(function(){

    $('.pagination').find('a').click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var pos = $(this).data('position');

        var $list = $('.list').find('li');

        $list
         .filter('[data-position='+pos+']')
         .insertAfter($list.first());

    })

});
```

Por não ser tão comum o uso deles no `jQuery`, aqui vai uma breve explicação:

`insertAfter` = Insere um determinado valor depois o elemento especificado

`filter` = Da lista dos elementos atuais, pega os elementos que casam com os valores passados no parâmetro. No caso acima, estamos especificando que o elemento tem que ter o `data-position` igual ao `data-position` do link clicado.

Estamos basicamente dizendo para o `jQuery`: "procure o elemento que tenha o data-position igual ao position do link clicado atual e insira ele depois do primeiro elemento da lista"

Código atualizado no [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybuf4fju/1/)

Comment: Dessa forma eu já fiz. O problema é que eu preciso reordenar a lista da forma como mostrei no texto a cima. Da forma que você fez ele apenas adiciona o elemento na posição desejada mas não reordena a lista.